# The semantics of Parsing Expression Grammars

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars, semantics, parsing

Is there a simple and intuitive explanation for the fact that the following parsing expression (where `S` is the starting symbol, `$` denotes end-of-string and `/` is ordered choice)

```
S <- X $
X <- 'a' X 'a' / 'aa'
```

only matches strings of 'a's with a length that is a **power** of 2? (The same grammar interpreted as a CFG would match strings of 'a's with a length that is a **multiple** of two.)

And how can PEGs be suitable for the specification of computer languages if ordered choice makes the language defined by a PEG that unintuitive to understand?

Comment: Not that I don't agree with your point (I do), but what more do you expect as an answer than a proof that this grammar indeed recognizes $\{a^{2^n}\mid n\geq 1\}$?  On the other hand people have been using PEGs for programming languages (e.g. [Fortress](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/FOOL09/allen-abstract.html), [Java and C](http://www.romanredz.se/freesoft.htm)), and there are lots of [implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar#Implementations) around, so just like Turing-complete languages and other unsafe tools people do useful stuff with it nevertheless.

Comment: PS: A similar question was answered by Christophe Grand on the [PEG mailing-list](http://www.mail-archive.com/peg@lists.csail.mit.edu/msg00110.html) a few years ago.

Comment: There is also interesting discussion on LtU http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3039#comment-44356 (good comment about ambiguity: "PEGs define away ambiguity, which means that you don't know where the real ambiguity is").